# Why can't curl retrieve the SSH host key (key: <none>)

Tags: ssh, curl

I've been using curl (by means of git-ftp) for a while, and passing only username and an `sftp` URL.

Authentication would always work implicitely through publickey.

Suddenly curl will not connect through SSH anymore – apparently because it does not get a host key and therefore rejects the connection:

`Trying {IP}...
* Connected to host.example.com ({IP}) port 22 (#0)
* SSH MD5 fingerprint: {Fingerprint}
* SSH host check: 2, key: <none>
* Closing connection 0`

**Why can't curl get the key?**

Connections with `ssh -v` work and do give me 2 host keys, also `curl --insecure` will work.

Comment: Actually for another SSH host not even the `--insecure` works, and the lines starting with SSH are not shown at all

Comment: Do you have the public host key stored in your `known_hosts` file?

Comment: Yes i do. SSH won't ask for it.

Comment: That is by design so that you can be alerted and identify a possible break in on the target server (if ssh host key is missing or if it was changed because the server was reinstalled of hacked).

Comment: Thx @marcel sure that's by design, but why can't curl get the key when everything is alright? SSH can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[libssh2 does not support some later keys like ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 and ssh-ed25519](https://github.com/libssh2/libssh2/issues/129).

So if you already have one of these keys in your *.ssh/known_hosts*, libssh2 will fail. But you can add another key that libssh2 supports, like RSA:

To fix it, retrieve the RSA public key from the remote host and add it to your `known_hosts` file:

`ssh-keyscan hostname.example.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts`

The exact format and file location might vary by system.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by replacing the ipv6 address with the domain, inside of the `known_hosts` file.

It happened to already exist in a file named `known_hosts2` in the same directory, but I guess this file is not actually read by ssh/curl.